# How to ensure RTTI generation in Delphi without creating a Dummy Reference?

Tags: delphi

I'm working with Delphi and attempting to leverage its RTTI system. However, I've noticed that unless I create a "dummy reference" to my class (i.e., instantiate or reference it somewhere in my code), its RTTI information isn't generated or might be optimized away by the compiler.

For example:

```
TMyObject = class(TObject)
public
  Title: String;
end;
```

If TMyObject isn't referenced anywhere in the code, it doesn't show up when I query the `TRttiContext.GetTypes`.

Is there a more elegant way or a compiler directive to ensure that RTTI is generated for classes without explicitly referencing them in the code? I'd prefer not to use workarounds like creating a dummy procedure if possible.

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you mark the class with the [`{$TYPEINFO ON}`/`{$M+}`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Run-Time_Type_Information_(Delphi)) directive? Otherwise, you could just reference the class in its own unit's `initialization` section, eg: `initialization TMyObject.Create.Free;`

Comment: I suppose [this](https://algosim.org/SynViewSource/ASFcnExp.html) doesn't count as "more elegant"?

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes same issue with {$TYPEINFO ON}/{$M+} :( doing initialization TMyObject.Create.Free; work but i was hopping that something like  {$TYPEINFO ON}/{$M+} could do the job but it's didn't :(

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand thanks yes look like i have not too much choice than something similar to your suggestion :(